# android is upgrading, starting apps boot loop

Tags: rom-flashing

I have a allview urban tab 7 tablet and it's stuck at this "android is upgrading, starting apps" boot loop. I haven't done anything to it like rooting or installing untrusted 3rd party apps other than facebook, gmail, and some official apps from the market. What can i do? It's driving me crazy and i have no idea what's wrong with it. Can you please help me?

Comment: How long have you left it for? It takes a while the first time